# python convert text rows to dictionary based on conditional match

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I have the below string and need help on how write an if condition in a for loop that check if the row.startswith('name') then take the  value and store is in a variable called name. Similarly for dob as well.

Once the for loop completes the output should be a dictionary as below which i can convert to a pandas dataframe.

```
'name john\n \n\nDOB\n12/08/1984\n\ncurrent company\ngoogle\n'
```

This is what i have tried so far but do not know how to get the values into a dictionary

```
for row in lines.split('\n'):

    if row.startswith('name'):

        name = row.split()[-1]
```

Final Ouput

```
data = {"name":"john", "dob": "12/08/1984"}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @sabik i have updated the post and the code i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list comprehension and `split`:

```
s = '''name
john

dob
12/08/1984

current company
google'''

d = dict([i.splitlines() for i in s.split('\n\n')])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'john', 'dob': '12/08/1984', 'current company': 'google'}
```

Comment: my bad, actually the text is type string. i have updated the source file in the original post. text = 'name john\n \n\nDOB\n12/08/1984\n\ncurrent company\ngoogle\n'

Comment: IT WORKS but as below name value is not right
----OUTPUT------
{'name john': ' ', 'DOB': '12/08/1984', 'current company': 'google'}